# php mySQLi change database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I know this should be really easy but I can't find the answer.

How do I change database in MySqli?

Here is my default connection code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass", "myDatabase");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

**What code here to select new database?**

UPDATE ANSWER: Found the line of code:

mysqli_select_db($con,"statues_Items");

Comment: Just made another $con with new params or rewrite the old one with your new database params

Comment: Robert, I thought about that but then I have to put my username and pass in that line every time. If I ever update I will have to change all the code later. I thought there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `mysqli_select_db`?
For example, `mysqli_select_db($con, "new_db");`

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: Oops. I noticed the OP had posted the answer right around the same time I did.

Answer (score -1):

By this

select  database1

```
$mysqli1 = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE1);
$mysqli1->query();
```

select database2

```
   $mysqli2 = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE2);
    $mysqli2->query();
```